# External Hard Disk folder closes randomly

Tags: external-hdd

I have a Seagate external hard disk of 500 gb, and when i connect it to my laptop, Ubuntu detects it without a finch. But when I open the corresponding folder, it remains open for sometime and then randomly closes without any error message, and also the ext hard disk still can be opened again, but I've to keep on opening it again and again to access it's folders which is very annoying. Can someone please suggest a fix??

Comment: Please provide the output of `dmesg` run in terminal.

Comment: It's too big, how should I post it to you??